# Google Charts Javascript Literal data notation gives "Not an array" error?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, syntax-error

When using Javascript Literal data in combination with Google Charts arrayToTable function, it returns an error in Javascript that states "Not an array" in the Modernizr-3.5.2.js file in line 
433 -> `ret = !!(window.WebGLRenderingContext && (canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl') || canvas.getContext('webgl')));`

Any ideas why? data object is generated as google chart api documentation states.

Code that generates chart is below:

```
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });

    function StackedColumnChart(ChartDivContainerID) { 

    var ChartData1 = {
            cols: [{ id: 'Genre', label: 'Genre', type: 'string' },
                   { id: 'Fantasy & Sci Fi', label: 'Fantasy & Sci Fi', type: 'number' },
                   { id: 'Romance', label: 'Romance', type: 'number' },
                   { id: 'Mystery/Crime', label: 'Mystery/Crime', type: 'number' },
                   { id: 'General', label: 'General', type: 'number' },
                   { id: 'Western', label: 'Western', type: 'number' },
                   { id: 'Literature', label: 'Literature', type: 'number' }
            ],
            rows: [{ c: [{ v: '2010' }, { v: 10 }, { v: 24 }, { v: 20 }, { v: 32 }, { v: 18 }, { v: 5 }] },
                   { c: [{ v: '2020' }, { v: 16 }, { v: 22 }, { v: 23 }, { v: 30 }, { v: 16 }, { v: 9 }] },
                   { c: [{ v: '2030' }, { v: 28 }, { v: 19 }, { v: 29 }, { v: 30 }, { v: 12 }, { v: 13 }] }
            ]
        }

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(ChartData1);

        var options = {
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
            bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
            isStacked: true,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById(ChartDivContainerID));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

Comment: what is JsonChartData?

Comment: Nothing relevant. Made a mistake when pasting from code to here. I corrected now the code above so it makes sense. In reality the ChartData1 is generated outside the function StackedColumnChart and is passed in as function parameter. For the purpose of demonstration i simplified it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data object is correct but you are calling

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(ChartData1);
```

instead of

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(ChartData1);
```